# Closing hamburger menu on menu icon and outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I close the hamburger menu on outside if it's been clicked on overlay.
I'm still new to js and here's my code. Right now its just working when closing the hamburger icon. I'm practicing but I can't seem to make it work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
        overlay = $('.overlay'),
        isClosed = false;

    trigger.click(function () {
        hamburger_cross();

    });

    function hamburger_cross() {

        if (isClosed == true) {          
            overlay.hide();
            trigger.removeClass('is-open');
            trigger.addClass('is-closed');
            isClosed = false;
        } else {   
            overlay.show();
            trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
            trigger.addClass('is-open');
            isClosed = true;
        }
    }

    $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener to the whole document to close the menu if it's open.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!isClosed || e.target.matches('.hamburger, .hamburger *')) return;

  // better to put this in its own function for DRY code
  overlay.hide();
  trigger.removeClass('is-open');
  trigger.addClass('is-closed');
  isClosed = false;
});
```

Comment: `not workin` is not helpful, what's the error? Did you put it in the proper scope?